# What is full form of MLP in MLP sub stream?

Tags: audio-streaming

In the context of DVD audio or any similar audio, what is the meaning of MLP substream? I have been looking for a full form at least, but did not find any on googling.

Regards,
Kiki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Meridian Lossless Packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_Lossless_Packing)